# How do I convert a string array to a LPCWSTR in .NET to pass to a Win32 API function?

Tags: .net, winapi, pinvoke, marshalling

I have a piece of C# code that needs to convert a string array to a LPCWSTR to pass to a Win32 API function. I can't find nothing in the Marshal class that makes it straightforward. Does anybody knows how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare the API function as taking a string array.  Since it's declared as constant, you should add an `In` attribute so that it's not marshalled back after the call.  If the function truly only has a unicode version as you've specified (i.e., it takes `LPCWSTR` and not `LPCTSTR`), then you should declare it with `CharSet=Unicode`.  Similar to:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=Unicode)]
static extern bool Foo([In] string[] stuff);
```

What API function are you trying to call?  If you post it, I can give you a good P/Invoke signature for it.  Or you can check [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/), which has a pretty good pre-compiled list (community-generated) of P/Invoke signatures.